# Подсветка синтаксиса логов в Linux

Tags: linux, bash, консоль, shell, логирование

Часто приходится смотреть логи различных приложений (nginx, unicron) на linux серверах. 
Очевидный факт, что разглядеть важную инфу будет гораздо легче, если там будет подсветка синтаксиса. Возможно ли в выводе logcat/less/cat да и просто терминала сделать подсветку ?
Подобное есть в VS Code. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как показывает многолетняя практика, разукраска логов только мешает найти там важную информацию. А если нужно анализировать логи, есть специальные сервисы - [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) или Slunk (по бюджету).

Comment: "в выводе logcat/less/cat да и просто терминала" подсветка уже есть. Может вопрос о том как распарсить неструктурированные / нераскрашенные логи для добавления к ним подсветки? Потребность "Часто приходится смотреть логи различных приложений" говорит о том, что у вас что-то уже не так.

Comment: @KoVadim, ELK или Slunk есть не везде, чего нельзя сказать в большинстве случаев про core utils.

Comment: @user7860670  
1 Если подсветка уже есть, вы могли бы поделиться ссылками на инфу ?
2 Я привел пример, что хочу увидеть на примере VS Code.
3 Смотря для какой задачи нужно смотреть логи. Руководствуясь вашей логикой, то смотреть в логи последнее дело)

Comment: В терминале обычно работают цвета на последовательностях VT1000. Некоторые программы уже сами генерируют цветные логи (тот же gcc), некоторые надо раскрашивать. см https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output Да, смотреть в логи - последнее дело. Ну или может быть предпоследнее - дальше уже идет gdb, strace и прочие непотребства.

Comment: @user7860670, вижу говорим в разных контекстах. Спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть программа multitail. Величина буфера просмотра указывается параметром -n. Вторая, для просмотра в режиме реального времени с очень хорошей подстветкой, lnav

Comment: Подходит. Можно обобщенный обработчик написать и все будет хорошо) P.s глядя в конфиг уже понятно как свою цветовую схему можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов есть вывода инфо в консоль - каждый настраивается отдельно. Вот небольшой список:

- [**dircolors**](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/ru/man1/dircolors.1.html) - настройка цветов для `ls`
- [**GREP_COLORS**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17236005/11141611) - настройка цветов для вывода `grep`
- [**bashrc**](https://rtfm.co.ua/bash-nastraivaem-konsol-pod-sebya/) - настройка цветов терминала `bash`

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте ccze, в логах постфикса прям вырвиглаз.